# Use GLFW in Xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, glfw

I'm having trouble getting GLFW to work on my Xcode 8 and getting the [demo](http://www.glfw.org/documentation.html) from the website working in Xcode. I'm using c++ through the command line type project in Xcode and I imported the cocoa and OpenGL frameworks. Using MacPorts and using `sudo port install glfw`, I got the libglfw.3.2.dylib and imported that framework into my project. However it still cannot recognise

```
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
```

As for some reason, Xcode is unable to find the file. What am I doing wrong? My aim is to create a graphical standalone executable file from Xcode through c++.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set search path in "Build Setting" to be where header file is, like for example: "/usr/local/include"